# How can i check if one of the same images is dragged and dropped on the other one in Corona?

Tags: drag-and-drop, coronasdk

I am trying to match images on Corona. I created  images and matches array variables and insert the display objects inside those arrays. However, i can't figure it out how i will be able to move one of the same objects onto other and make it disappear. Can you help me out? Thanks.

Here is my code so far:

```
    local images={}
    local matches={}

    local function onTouch( event )
       local t = event.target
       local phase = event.phase

if "began" == phase then
    -- Make target the top-most object
    local parent = t.parent
    parent:insert( t )
    display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( t )

    t.isFocus = true
elseif t.isFocus then
    if "moved" == phase then
        t.x = event.x
        t.y = event.y 
elseif "ended" == phase or "cancelled" == phase then
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
        t.isFocus = false
    end
end

  return true
   end



  local arguments =
   {
{img="img1.png" , x=30, y=30 },
{img="img2.png", x=100, y=30},
{img= "img3.png",x=170, y=30},
   }    

    local arguments2={

{img= "img1.png",x=30, y=150},
{img= "img2.png",x=100, y=150},
{img= "img3.png",x=170, y=150}

     }

   for _,item in ipairs( arguments ) do
local imgg = display.newImage( item.img,item.x,item.y )

table.insert(images,imgg)
-- Make the button instance respond to touch events
imgg:addEventListener( "touch", onTouch )
   end

   for _,item in ipairs( arguments2 ) do
local imgg = display.newImage( item.img,item.x,item.y )

table.insert(matches,imgg)
-- Make the button instance respond to touch events
imgg:addEventListener( "touch", onTouch )
   end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easiest to assign a type or the like to each image, eg;
{img="img1.png" , x=30, y=30, type="red" }

Then when it is released check whether or not it is within the content bounds of the matching image in the other arguments table using object.contentBounds (you can find detailed info about this on the Corona Labs API page.)